# Laravel 7 dropdownlist public function create

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem when adding data from the form. I have 2 dropdown list fields. I want to select a person from one field and a computer from another. At the moment I can only select one field, the other does not read data from the database. In the controller, I created public function create (), but it only works for the first person position.

```
public function create()
    {
       $magazyns = Blog::all(['id','name','surname','lastname']);

       return view('magazyns.create',compact('magazyns'));

        $magazyns = Computers::all(['id','name']);

        return view('magazyns.create',compact('magazyns'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass one variable to view.

You should:

```
public function create()
{
   $magazyns_blog = Blog::all(['id','name','surname','lastname']);
   $magazyns_computer = Computers::all(['id','name']);

   return view('magazyns.create',compact('magazyns_blog','magazyns_computer'));
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong... Undefined variable: magazyns (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel7\resources\views\magazyns\create.blade.php)